# Can install django-rosetta package using "easy_install"

Tags: python, django, osqa, django-rosetta

I have django 1.2.4, Python 2.6.6 and latest osqa[july2012] installed on bluehost. 
I would like to translate the osqa app[works fine] using rosetta. 
I am using terminal on mac with ssh connection.

osqa is here

```
 ~/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/osqa/
```

When I want to install rosetta I run `easy_install django-rosetta` and I get the following error:

```
    error: can't create or remove files in install directory
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the installation directory: [Errno 30] 
Read-only file system: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-28753.write-test'The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
    the distutils default setting) was:/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
```

How can I make it writable? 
The installation of osqa, django and python went smoothly but rosetta just doesnt want. 
I have ran the `easy_install django-rosetta` in the root dir and in site-packages dir.

Comment: ~/.local/bin/easy_install --prefix=~/.local Django-rosetta worked! :) Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

In the long run you're much better off using `virtualenv`